Custom volume indicator for future indices volume above 50K show in spot indices
I want to see future indices volume in the Spot chart with customized volume only above 50K. For this, I made the script. It's working fine in future charts however volume bars are not getting highlighted in the spot chart as required.
what am I doing wrong?

Future Indices: NSE:BANKNIFTY1!

Spot Indices: NSE:BANKNIFTY


Result with current code in spot chart:
Above threshold volume bars are not getting highlighted

Required result in spot chart:

the script:
//@version=4
study("Banknifty volume",resolution="",format=format.volume)

Averageval1 = input(title='Average Volume BankNifty', defval=50, minval=1)
string i_maType2 = syminfo.prefix + ":" + syminfo.ticker
hi_vol= i_maType2=="NSE:BANKNIFTY1!"?Averageval1 * 1000:na

a= security("NSE:Banknifty1!",timeframe.period, volume)

/// Marking bull bear

Bear= input(defval = color.new(color.red,0), title = "Bearish", group = "Colors")
Bull= input(defval = color.new(color.green,0), title = "Bullish", group = "Colors")
std=input(defval = color.new(#d1d4dc,0), title = "Std Bull", group = "Colors")

colorofbar = open < close and volume>hi_vol? Bull:open > close and volume>hi_vol? 
Bear:std

plot(a, color = colorofbar, style=plot.style_columns, title="Banknifty volume")


I was working on something similar on version 5 check it out
    // This Pine Script™ code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © Codex Maximus

//@version=5
indicator("BNF VOL ON SPOT")
avgvol = input(title = "Avg volume for BNF",defval = 50000)
barcolor = color.gray

//get volume of banknifty
bnffutvol = request.security("NSE:BANKNIFTY1!",timeframe.period,volume)

//BULL AND BEAR CANDLE
bull = open < close and bnffutvol > avgvol
bear = open > close and bnffutvol > avgvol

//define geater than 50k parameter
abvavgerage = bull ? color.green : color.gray

//check whether bull or bear 
if bull
    barcolor := color.green
else if bear
    barcolor := color.red
else
    barcolor := color.gray


plot(bnffutvol,style = plot.style_columns, color = barcolor)

